# How to order the keys of Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the below dictionary and I would like to print the keys in the order:
`[Name,Gender,Occupation,Location]`

```
{'Gender': 'Male',
 'Location': 'Nizampet,Hyderabad',
 'Name': 'Srikanth',
 'Occupation': 'Data Scientist'}
```

Can someone suggest how it can be done.

Comment: How did you come up with the expected keys list ? On what basis did you order them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can arrange the order of keys when you create the dictionary.

> Python 3.7+
>
> In Python 3.7.0 the insertion-order preservation nature of
> dict objects has been declared to be an official part of the Python
> language spec. Therefore, you can depend on it.

```
old_dict = {'Gender': 'Male', 'Location': 'Nizampet,Hyderabad', 'Name': 'Srikanth', 'Occupation': 'Data Scientist'}

new_dict = {
    "Name": old_dict["Name"],
    "Gender": old_dict["Gender"],
    "Occupation": old_dict["Occupation"],
    "Location": old_dict["Location"]
}

print(new_dict)
```

Output

```
{'Name': 'Srikanth', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Occupation': 'Data Scientist', 'Location': 'Nizampet,Hyderabad'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a predetermined order in which you'd like to print the data, store the order in a list of keys and loop through them.

```
data = {
    'Gender': 'Male',
    'Location': 'Nizampet,Hyderabad',
    'Name': 'Srikanth',
    'Occupation': 'Data Scientist'
}

print_order = [
    'Name',
    'Gender',
    'Occupation',
    'Location',
]

for key in print_order:
    print(f'{key}: {data[key]}')
```

Output:

```
$ python3 print_dict_in_order.py
Name: Srikanth
Gender: Male
Occupation: Data Scientist
Location: Nizampet,Hyderabad
```